# Keep quotation marks inside the file when writing string into a file python

Tags: python

I would like to write file with python

My code is producing:

```
{ date: 2018-11-28, weight: 172.91, height: 177.65, id:310 }
```

I want to have the following is the input inside the file

```
{ date: '2018-11-28', weight: 172.91, height: 177.65, id:310 }
```

With the single quote mark which I need it to be there.

Any help please for writing string into file with single quote mark ' .

my code:

```
my_dict = { 'date': '2018-11-28', 'weight': 172.91, 'height': 177.65, 'id':310 }
my_dict = str(my_dict)
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
f.write(my_dict)
f.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: This is the what your code is producing. `{'date': '2018-11-28', 'weight': 172.91, 'height': 177.65, 'id': 310}`. Which quotes you want and don't want?

Comment: I dont want them all except the ones with '2018-11-28'

Comment: just add single quotes to the string then...

Comment: This is a very strange request. Are you sure you don't just want to save it as _json_ using `json.dump()`?

Comment: Try this:
New line 2:
my_dict["date"] = "'" + str(my_dict["date"]) + "'"

Comment: In saying that, I do second Gordon's motion - you probably want to use JSON or similar

Comment: Can you tell us why you need that very specific and odd format? Which parser is supposed to read your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library.
In your case you would use:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_dict, f, indent=4)
```

Or, to mimic your approach to files:

```
f = open('file.txt', w)
json.dump(my_dict, f, indent=4)
f.close()
```

Comment: This won't print single quotes. But double quotes instead.

Comment: I tried your code it did not solve it